# SeekBar for recording 30 second sound - handleReceiveCallback error

Tags: java, android, handler, audio-recording, seekbar

I've been trying to allow users to record sounds that are up to 30 seconds long, and using a SeekBar to indicate how much they've recorded so far. I've got some code I pieced together from a variety of instructions online, but I keep getting an NPE and "Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback"/"Exception dispatching input event" error. I'm not sure how to interpret this or what I'm doing wrong. Through log tags, I can tell that it gets as far as StartRecording() and then throws an exception when the Handler is called to track the recording length. Can anyone see the problem? Code below:

Inside AudioRecorder class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;


public class AudioRecorder {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/audio"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".3gp";
    private static MediaRecorder mRecorder;
    private static MediaPlayer   mPlayer;
    public boolean isRecording;
    public boolean isPlaying;
    int recordTime;
    Handler handler;

    public void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }

    }

    public void onPlay(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startPlaying();
        } else {
            stopPlaying();
        }

    }

    public void startPlaying() {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(fileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
        isPlaying = true;
    }

    public void stopPlaying() {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
        isPlaying = false;
    }

    public void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recordTime = 0;

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        Log.w("LCC", "Start playing made it this far! 1!");

        mRecorder.start();
        isRecording = true;
        handler.post(UpdateRecordTime);
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.reset();
        mRecorder = null;
        isRecording = false;
        handler.removeCallbacks(UpdateRecordTime);
    }

    public void playSound(Context c){
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileName);
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, uri);

            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    stopPlayer();
                }
            });
        }

        mPlayer.start();
    }

    public void stopPlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    Runnable UpdateRecordTime = new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
             if(isRecording){ 
                  recordTime++;
                  // Delay 1s before next call      
                  handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
         }
    };

    public int getCurrentPosition(){
        return recordTime;
    };
}
```

And inside AudioRecorderActivity class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class AudioRecorderActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private AudioRecorder mRecorder = new AudioRecorder();
    //private View mPlayButton;
    //private View mStopButton;
    //private View mRecordButton;
    private View mRecordButton;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private boolean isRecording;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                       // WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBar);
        mSeekBar.setMax(30);

        mRecordButton = findViewById(R.id.recordPlayButton);
        mRecordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(event.getAction()){
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     mRecorder.onRecord(true);
                     isRecording = true;

                    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                    final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(mRecorder.isRecording){
                                int mCurrentPosition = mRecorder.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                                mSeekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                            }
                            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                        }
                    };

                     break;
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                     mRecorder.stopRecording();
                     isRecording = false;
                     break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Edit: here is the exact error (there are two sets that occur whenever I press the record button)

```
02-03 17:17:28.189: W/LCC(3757): Start playing made it this far! 1!
02-03 17:17:28.579: E/InputEventReceiver(3757): Exception dispatching input event.
02-03 17:17:28.579: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at com.littlecloudcollective.waves.AudioRecorder.startRecording(AudioRecorder.java:80)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at com.littlecloudcollective.waves.AudioRecorder.onRecord(AudioRecorder.java:28)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at com.littlecloudcollective.waves.AudioRecorderActivity$1.onTouch(AudioRecorderActivity.java:43)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7229)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2177)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1482)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2469)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:260)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2125)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7414)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3523)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3455)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4565)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4543)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-03 17:17:28.599: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3757):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 17:17:28.599: D/AndroidRuntime(3757): Shutting down VM
02-03 17:17:28.599: W/dalvikvm(3757): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41104438)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at com.littlecloudcollective.waves.AudioRecorder.startRecording(AudioRecorder.java:80)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at com.littlecloudcollective.waves.AudioRecorder.onRecord(AudioRecorder.java:28)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at com.littlecloudcollective.waves.AudioRecorderActivity$1.onTouch(AudioRecorderActivity.java:43)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7229)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1936)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2177)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1482)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2469)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:260)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2125)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7414)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3523)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3455)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4565)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4543)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4647)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-03 17:17:28.609: E/AndroidRuntime(3757):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please Post Exact error

Comment: Hi @koutuk, just posted it - thanks!

Comment: What is in the lines that are mentioned in the stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @user2875404, I can tell that it's getting as far as the "handler.post(UpdateRecordTime);" under StartRecording() in AudioRecorder, because of that initial log tag that shows. I believe that's where the error is occurring.

Comment: How can you not tell the line names? "at AudioRecorder.java:80"  "at  AudioRecorder.java:28" ?

Comment: @user2875404, both line 80 and 28 point to closing brackets but right before 80, as I said, is "handler.post(UpdateRecordTime);" and line 27 is "startRecording()"

Comment: I think you didn't create the Handler properly. Do you do handler=new Handler(); anywhere else?

Comment: That solved the crashing, @user2875404, thank you so much!! But the SeekBar still isn't working - I suppose that's for another open question, though. Would mark that answer as correct if you put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to create a new object of the Handler. Add

```
handler=new Handler();
```

to the `AudioRecorder` class and you'll be fine.

Also, I think you made another mistake concerning setting the value:

`getCurrentPosition()` will return a value between 0 and 30. When you call `getCurrentPosition()/1000` it technically can't go above 0, as `int1/int1+int2` will always return 0. Seekbar takes a range from 0 to 100. Comment out the `/1000` so it is

```
int mCurrentPosition = mRecorder.getCurrentPosition();
                       mSeekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
```

and you should be fine.

`getCurrentPosition()*10/3` will make the Seekbar reach its end when the recording hits the 30 sec mark.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually also noticed the / 1000 bit and thought that would fix it, but it oddly did not...there must be some sort of issue with the multiple threads. Looking into it more now. Thanks again

Comment: Solution, just as a heads up to anyone who has a similar issue - I got the SeekBar to work by simply calling the Runnable! I instantiate it but never call it. Execute mRunnable.run() right after defining it and bam, it works.